# How we can resolve org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Applicant is not mapped

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate configuration file as follows

```
    en<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mining</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping resource="../WEB-INF/mams-hibern.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The mams-hibern.xml contains mapping files configured as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantAddressHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantContactHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantLeases.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/GeneratedChallan.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenderType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceDetailRule.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TemperoryAppNotes.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TemperoryFilePath.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OtherDocuments.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceSubactsRules.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/OffenceActRules.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Vehicles.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApprovedMajorMineral.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/GoogleImage.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/PasswordHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/LeaseTransfer.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/TransferApplicantCompany.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/MailSettings.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/LeaseCompanyAddress.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/FinancialYear.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/IncomeTax.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AdditionalCharge.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/MenuPrivileges.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AddressType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AdvaloramRoyalty.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Agent.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AppJawsize.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Applicant.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantAddress.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantCompany.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantContact.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantLogin.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicantStatus.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Application.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationDocument.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationHistory.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationMineral.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSpecificQuery.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSpecificQueryValues.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationStatus.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationSurvey.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplicationType.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/ApplnSecurityFee.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/AreaSpecification.hbm.xml</value>
<value>nic/mams/model/Bank.hbm.xml</value>
</property>
</beans>
```

But I get exception

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Applicant is not mapped d [select a from Applicant as a inner join a.applications as b inner join b.applicationType as c inner join b.permits as d where d.permitNo=? and c.applicationTypeId=?]

What is the solution for this.Any one know please help me

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge and my research goes, two things might get you into the kind of exception that you are getting.

1. Check that your hql queries refer to entity/property names, not
   table/column names. See
   [Hibernate error - QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [from users]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954590/hibernate-error-querysyntaxexception-users-is-not-mapped-from-users)
2. Check that the class 'name' attribute is pointing to the entity
   class appropriately. See [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped [from table]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144316/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-table-is-not-mapped-from-t)